# Burn subtitles with emojis on a video in android java

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, video-subtitles

video.mp4, subtitles.ass

the ass file contains emojis. how to burn it on a video? I tried ffmpeg.

ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "ass=subtitles.ass" -c:a copy -c:v h264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast output.mp4

but the emojis are not showing. instead, rectangles are showing. it happens in every font I choose.

subtitles.ass:
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding

Style: Default,opensans_bold,59,&Hffb3b4,&HF0000000,&H000000,&HF0000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,5,0,2,64,64,604,1

[Events]

Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text

Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:00.68,Default,,0,0,0,,yes

Comment: Looks like FFmpeg doesn't support it (see: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5777). You would need to use another tool (possibly AndroidX Media3).

Comment: thanks but can it burn subtitles on video?

Comment: I'm not sure, but they have something called TextOverlay.